# Help with bash script with text

Tags: bash

I'm new in bash scripting and need help with the following please:

The purpose of this homework is to let students write programs in bash scripting language that enable them to manipulate data in a text file similarly to a database table..

Students should understand the table structure and write the programs check_table, row_select and row_delete using bash scripting language.

Table structure
A table consists of a text file that contains lines. The first line contains information about the
table and each of the rest of lines represents a data row.

The first line structure is as follows:

```
table_name:number_of_rows:number_of_fields:fieldname1,fieldname2,filedname3 ...etc
```

- table_name is an alphanumeric string not exceeding 16 characters and does not include the
  column character ‘:’ nor the space character ‘ ‘. It must be the same as the file name.
- number_of_rows is a integer with value less than 1000.
- number_of_fields is a integer with value less than 10.
- filedname is an alphanumeric string not exceeding 16 characters and not including the space ‘ ‘ nor the comma ‘,’ characters.

Each data row consists of a series of fields delimited by the comma character’,’. Each row has
exactly the same number of fields as all other fields in the table. A field consists of a string
of alphanumeric characters, does not exceed 16 characters and does not contain the space
character ‘ ‘ nor the comma character ‘,’.

Example:

```
students_info:3:5:std_1st_name,std_last_name,year_ of_birth,sex,program
amer,salim,1990,m,bit
samira,rami,1988,f,ise
lamia,rida,1990,f,ise
```

Programs

1.check_table

```
syntax: check_table <table_name>
```

Description:

The program checks the following in order:

- command syntax
- table exists.
- first line syntax is correct.
- tablename and fieldnames all have correct lengths.
- Table has correct number of rows.
- All rows have correct number of fields.

Output:

- table  is good
- table  has a a problem
  problem description (first problem encountered)

example:

```
$ check_table students_info
table students_info is good
$ check_table student_info1
table students_info has at least one problem:
Actual number of rows not equal to the one in the file header.
```

I need some guide about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I couldn't figure how to start ?
Can you guide me on this please ?

Comment: how to start: write #!/bin/bash -xv at the top of a file. Save it. Then, make the file executatble: $chmod +x fileName  You actualy dont need to do that, but it makes like easier. You could do sudo exec ./filename every-time you want to run your program.

Answer (score 4):

You should at least start by learning the basics of bash. I recommend reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide.

After reading the guide, you'll want to look at parsing a text file line-by-line and/or field-by-field, which [Bash FAQ 1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) explains.

You'll also need to do some string manipulations. [Bash FAQ 100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) should cover that.

Answer (score -1):

Just to help you get started, save this in a file and set the execute mode then run it in a terminal. Look at the output and compare it to the script. See if you can understand how it relates. Use the reference that have already been suggested to help.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# != 1 ]]
then
    echo usage $0 "<table_to_check>"
    exit 1
fi

error=""
firstline=1
{
    while read line # loop through the lines
    do
    # check syntax of "line"
        if(($firstline))
        then
        #check first line syntax
            echo information row=$line # debug

            # ... your method here. Assign to error if something is wrong...

            firstline=0 # ready for next line/loop which should be data
        else
        #check other lines
            echo data row=$line # debug

            # ... your method here. Assign to error if something is wrong...

        fi


        if [[ $error != "" ]] # assign any error in the data as a string message you can then print here and exit
        then
            echo $error 
            exit 2
        fi
    done
} < "$1"

exit 0 # no error
```

To implement the field  checks perhaps take a look at `cut` to break the line up into individual tokens, eg in the information row:

```
number_of_rows=`echo $line | cut -d':' -f2`
```

and given the sample, $number_of_rows should contain "3"

So to check this is right you could use a counter that gets incremented on each loop:

```
rowcount=$[rowcount+1]
```

When there is no more data $rowcount should equal $number_of_rows so:

```
    if (( $rowcount != $number_of_rows ))
    then
        error="number of rows doesn't agree"
        # ... etc ...
```

Something like that.

Other methods are available of course

Comment: `< <(cat $1)` is better written `< "$1"`; no point in first having cat read the file, then the shell. Also, quotes.

Comment: Some more improvements: Splitting out each field of a line using cut is very inefficient, better use read. `IFS=: read -ra fields <<< "$line"; echo "First field is ${fields[0]}, second is ${fields[1]}, ..."` (See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). The `$[ ... ]` syntax for doing math has been deprecated for ages. It's not even documented anymore. Use `rowcount=$(( rowcount + 1 ))` or `((rowcount++))`.